Azure functions GDAL support
I have a python project a which is running on azure functions. Which require GDAL library as well. for current setup to install gdal i used the wheel installation method but when i changed the python version from 3.10 to 3.11 there is no wheel available for Linux is there any solution for this problem.
current installation way
in req.txt file contain
/gdal.whl
Tried to find the GDAL wheel for linux based python 3.11. Nothing available is there any alternate way to install gdal in azure function (linux based)

You can  install GDAL-3.6.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl in Python 3.11 Azure Functions.

I have followed below steps and able to install GDAL in Linux Python Azure Function.

Download GDAL-3.6.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl from the Website.

Create a Python Azure Function.

Create a new folder named wheelhouse in the root directory of the function project and paste the downloaded GDAL file.


Project Structure:
│   .funcignore
│   .gitignore
│   function_app.py
│   host.json
│   local.settings.json
│   requirements.txt
├───.python_packages
├───.vscode
├───env
└───wheelhouse
        GDAL-3.6.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl


Give the path of GDAL file in the requirements.txt.

Requirements.txt:
azure-functions
./wheelhouse/GDAL-3.6.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

Function Code Snippet:
import datetime
import json
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from osgeo import gdal

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response. Gdal Version is: "+gdal.__version__,
             status_code=200
        )


Deploy the function to Azure:
Able to install GDAL package:


Console Response:
(env) C:\Users\uname\pyfunc>func azure functionapp publish functionappname

Getting site publishing info...
[2024-04-04T07:52:43.144Z] Starting the function app deployment...
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
Deleting the old .python_packages directory
Uploading 64.16 MB [##############################################################################]
Remote build in progress, please wait...
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id '98935773-e'.
PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Running oryx build...
Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /tmp/build/expressbuild --platform python --platform-version 3.11 -i /tmp/8dc547c5e3a49e4 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.20230508.1, Commit: 7fe2bf39b357dd68572b438a85ca50b5ecfb4592, ReleaseTagName: 20230508.1

Build Operation ID: d7bf2b863788d653
Repository Commit : 98935773-eeb5-47cd-b1be-dce6142af983
OS Type           : bullseye
Image Type        : githubactions

Detecting platforms...
Detected following platforms:
  python: 3.11.8

Using intermediate directory '/tmp/8dc547c5e3a49e4'.

Copying files to the intermediate directory...
Done in 0 sec(s).

Source directory     : /tmp/8dc547c5e3a49e4
Destination directory: /tmp/build/expressbuild

Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.8/bin/python3.11
Creating directory for command manifest file if it does not exist
Removing existing manifest file

Running pip install...
Done in 4 sec(s).
[07:53:56+0000] Processing ./wheelhouse/GDAL-3.6.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
[07:53:56+0000] Collecting azure-functions
[07:53:56+0000]   Downloading azure_functions-1.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (173 kB)
[07:53:56+0000] Installing collected packages: GDAL, azure-functions
[07:53:59+0000] Successfully installed GDAL-3.6.4 azure-functions-1.18.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 24.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.8/bin/python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Not a vso image, so not writing build commands
Preparing output...

Copying files to destination directory '/tmp/build/expressbuild'...
Done in 3 sec(s).

Removing existing manifest file
Creating a manifest file...
Manifest file created.
Copying .ostype to manifest output directory.

Done in 7 sec(s).
Writing the artifacts to a Zip file
Running post deployment command(s)...

Generating summary of Oryx build
Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!

Portal:

I could see Gdal Version 3.6.4 got installed in portal:



Thank you for your support to solve this issue. This worked for me
